# Kurtosis remains constant over different shaped normal distributions?

Tags: python, scipy, normal-distribution, scipy.stats, kurtosis

I want to explore the normal distribution with the same mean, but
changing std.

I expect that the Kurtosis will change with the std,
but in my results the Kurtosis stays constant?

**What is the issue here?**

At first I generated some normal distribution with shifting std:

> nd_l_std_44 = {}
> for i in range(1,10):
> >> nd_std_44 = stats.norm.rvs(loc=0, scale=i, size=10000, random_state=5)
> >> nd_l_std_44["ndl_std_{i}".format(i=i)] = nd_std_44
> print(nd_l_std_44.keys())

This worked and I did get a dict with different values for each key.

I did plot the resulting distributions:

[image]

I expected this. The Kurtosis is different, while the mean remains the same.
Now I calculated the Kurtosis in many ways, e.g. with scipy.stats

> kurt_std_1 = dict()
> for k,v in nd_l_std_44.items():
> >> kurt_std_1[k] = stats.kurtosis(v, fisher=False)
> print(kurt_std_1)

The problem is, I do get the same Kurtosis for all distributions.
This is also the case with Pandas.
I expected significant different Kurtosis values for distributions with different std. Instead the values are largely equal.)

{
'ndl_std_1': -0.0690005257753592,
'ndl_std_2': -0.0690005257753592,
'ndl_std_3': -0.0690005257753592,
'ndl_std_4': -0.0690005257753592,
'ndl_std_5': -0.06900052577535831,
'ndl_std_6': -0.0690005257753592,
'ndl_std_7': -0.06900052577535876,
'ndl_std_8': -0.0690005257753592,
'ndl_std_9': -0.0690005257753592
}

What is happening here? Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is to be expected.   As noted in the [wikipedia article on kurtosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurtosis), the kurtosis of any univariate [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) is 3 (and the [excess kurtosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurtosis#Excess_kurtosis) is therefore 0).  It is independent of both the mean and the standard deviation.

Comment: Thanks, looked into it.